# Confused about differentation and integration of power series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

in ii), I'm unsure why the term next to $c_0$ is $x-a$. When you find the antiderivative of a constant, say $c_0$, isn't it just $cx$? Where did the a come from?

Comment: When you integrate $c_0$ with respect to $x$ you could get $c_0x +K$ which could also be written $c_0(x-a)+(K+c_0 a)$, i.e. as $c_0(x-a)+C$, where $K$ and $C$ are constants

Comment: I suppose the desire is to present the whole as a power series in $(x-a)$ .

Comment: Oh I see, K+c0a is just another constant

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate $c_0(x-a)$ and check if it gives $c_0$.